# Module Returns Two Values for Plot; I need to Color them

Tags: plotting, graphics

This is probably a very stupid question, but I've been fighting with it for quite awhile now.

So suppose you have a module:

```
Test[g_] := Module[{r = g, r2},
r2 = g + 2;
Return[{g, r2}];
];
```

That module returns two values such that you can plot them (I've tried it with and without the {} around the function):

```
Plot[{Test[g]}, {g, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

I need to have them colored. I realize I can do this:

```
Plot[{Test[g][[1]], Test[g][[2]]}, {g, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

However, Test is just an example to ask this question, my real module takes a half an hour to plot (it is doing a bunch of maximizations, etc).  So, doing the last option would double that time. (and I want to make a bunch of plots).

So, does anyone know how to color the lines when in the first form such that I'm not running the module twice?

Comment: The problem is that due to the adaptive plotting capability of `Plot[]`, the sampling points used for plotting the first component do not at all need to be the same as the points for the second component, most especially if one component varies more than the other.

Comment: Try `Plot[Evaluate@Test[g], {g, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]`! This is a know issue with `Plot`.

Comment: Here's an example that might illustrate the problem for everybody else: ponder on the output of `Plot[Re[WeierstrassInvariants[{1 + I u, 1 - I u}]], {u, 1, 2}, Mesh -> All]`.

Comment: As a point of note, `Return` is not necessary here. Instead, simply use `{g, r2}`, and as the last expression in the [`CompoundExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CompoundExpression.html), it is the value "returned." More correctly, the `CompoundExpression` has that value, hence it is the `Module`'s value, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
Plot[Evaluate@Test[g], {g, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

This is a known issue with `Plot`. It happens because of the `HoldAll` attribute of `Plot`. You can check it

```
ClearAttributes[Plot, HoldAll]
Plot[Test[g], {g, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

However in practice we use `Evaluate` in place of messing with the attributes as it can result into unpredictable side effects.

**Smapling Issue:**

Following the adaptive meshing issue raised in the comment one should understand `Plot` by default may sample more often for some of the components that will result into computation of the other components as well in this case (particularly for the problem suggested by the OP). To see this try the following oscillating example

```
Test[g_] := Module[{r2},
 r2 = g^2 Sin[1/(g - 2)];
 {r2, g}];
{pic, data} = 
Reap[Plot[Evaluate@Test[g], {g, 1, 4}, Mesh -> All, 
     MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.01], Opacity[.45], Black], 
     PlotStyle -> {Red, {Blue, Thick}}, Frame -> True, Axes -> None, 
     EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{g, #} & /@ Test[g]]]]; 
pic
```

[image]

At first it seems less sample points were used for the linear component. But looking at the true sampling points using `EvaluationMonitor` one gets to see how adaptive meshing of `Plot` controls the evaluation of the function `Test`.

```
ListPlot[Transpose@First@data, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue},Frame -> True, Axes -> None]
```

[image]

BR

Comment: The OP mentions "...it is doing a bunch of maximizations, etc...", which leads me to suspect that what we have is a numerical function that happens to return two outputs.

Comment: @0x4A4D I got your point very well. I also updated the answer a bit to show this issue.